# Caffe Copy PreTrained Weights of AlexNet to custom network that has Two AlexNets

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, convolution

I am trying to build a network that contains two image inputs. Each image will go through a network simultaneous with late fusion that will merge and give one outputs. I use a diagram below to show what I need (ps: sorry my english is not so good)

[image]

My network defined in caffe prototxt model definition file which contains exact AlexNet defined twice upto the Pool 5. For first network the layers has same name as in [AlexNet](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_alexnet/train_val.prototxt) while for the second net  I added a *"_1"* suffix to each layer name. 
My question is how can i copy the pretained weight?

For Eg: my convolution layer 1 of each network is as follows. Note that for `conv1` the pretrained weights can easily be copied since the layer name is same as one in pretrained model. However of `conv1_1` the same is different so I am afraid I cannot copy the pretrained weights? Or is there a way to do this even is the layer names are different?

```
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data1"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 11
    stride: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}


layer {
  name: "conv1_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data2"
  top: "conv1_1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 11
    stride: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you are trying to finetune the whole network after initialization, otherwise you could simply use features extracted from AlexNet and start your training at the FC layer. For finetuning, you will need to copy the weights on the first network (one with the same names), and have second network share the weights with the first one. Take a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/jc0Jx4JjWwo) thread. Or rather [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/caffe-users/jc0Jx4JjWwo/4yhRN6o5FgAJ) reply from Evan Shelmar.

Comment: Yes I am trying to FineTune not just feature extraction. Thanks for pointing out those helpful links. I am still confused how the share those weights. Could you give some examples please. Besides I  didnt knew it was called a Siamese Net.

Comment: If you look at the reply to the comment I pointed out, there are [sample prototext](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/caffe-users/jc0Jx4JjWwo/J2CSIa9VFgAJ) files that OP posted.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar, here you can see the Siamese Network with Identical AlexNet. [Identical AlexNet for Siamese Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7QaJ.png). Here is [prototxt file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oej5c7sq5ti1f9x/ferrmenta_siamese_alexnet.prototxt?dl=0)

Comment: did you able to train two identical AlexNet with mnist dataset? @kcc__

Comment: are you training it on your own dataset or mnist dataset? @kcc__

Comment: I am using my own datasets of about 80K images. I havent trained yet. Did you try on MNIST yet? My GPU shuts down when I run caffe which I think is due to PSU so I have ordered a new one.

Comment: I am currently running four experiments. 1. Siamese network using LeNet on mnist dataset, 2. Siamese Network using AlexNet on mnist dataset, 3. Siamese network using LeNet on my own dataset, 2. Siamese Network using AlexNet on my own dataset. I didn't get good clustering with AlexNet. @kcc__

Comment: I want to calculate the accuracy for Siamese network using LeNet on mnist dataset. Do you know how we can do that @kcc__

Comment: If I get you correct do you mean Precision/Recall? Thats perhaps the standard way I am used to calculating the accuracy.

Comment: yeah, do you have any idea how we can do that?

Comment: Checkout this python layer from nvidia caffe which they use to compute the precision at test time. https://github.com/NVIDIA/caffe/blob/caffe-0.15/python/caffe/layers/detectnet/mean_ap.py

Comment: can you share your dataset @kcc__